# Does a non-extinct gliding species of bird exist?

Tags: ornithology, species, flight

According to wikipedia was Archaeopteryx rather glider than capable of active flight. As a hunting strategy it crawl up to a tree (or other high positioned place) and glide from it to a prey.

**Most of the modern birds are capable of active flight. Does anybody know if a (purely) gliding species of bird exist in present?**

Comment: That's really not how Archaeopteryx hunted, maniraptorans have really abysmal climbing ability, and Archaeopteryx shows no improvement on that. The current consensus is that Archaeopteryx was an active flier, albeit a poor one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a classification of birds called Soaring birds.

### Soaring Birds

> In definition, some land birds, such as vultures and certain hawks,
> sustain flight for long periods without flapping their wings. They
> take advantage of updrafts produced when the wind blows over hills and
> mountain ridges or make use of rising columns of warm air called
> "thermals."
>
> Vultures stay within thermals by flying slowly in tight circles. They
> have short, broad wings and a low wing loading (ratio of bird weight
> to wing area) that allows them to remain aloft and to be highly
> maneuverable at slow speeds. [1]

### [List of soaring birds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_soaring_birds)

- **Birds of Prey**

  - Buzzards
  - Condors
  - Eagles
  - Falcons
  - Harriers
  - Hawks
  - Kites
  - Osprey
  - Secretary Bird
  - Vultures
- **Passerine**

  - Chough
- **Cranes**

  - Sandhill
- **Sea birds**

  - Albatrosses
  - Frigatebirds
  - Gulls
  - Herons
  - Pelicans
  - Petrels
  - Shearwaters
  - Storks
  - Terns
- **Extinct**

  - Argentavis

### Buzzard

[image]

### Chough

[image]

### Sandhill

[image]

### Albatrosses

[image]
<sub>(source: [scienceviews.com](http://www.scienceviews.com/animals/images/SIA2842.jpg))</sub>

### Argentavis[Extinct]

[image]
<sub>(source: [mnn.com](http://www.mnn.com/sites/default/files/styles/featured_blog/public/gall_argentavis2.jpg))</sub>

### Update:

### Most similar morphology to Archaeopteryx is found in Hoatzin (*Opisthocomus hoazin*) like claws as hands as they hold the branch when they are small.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pbworks.com](http://watersgooberswiki.pbworks.com/f/1172371778/Q1_babyhoatz.gif))</sub>

Source:

[1] Soaring Birds by Paul R. Ehrlich, David S. Dobkin, and Darryl Wheye.

Comment: Hi @Devashishish Das!. Thank you for your answer, howerver I can not accept it. I am looking for "pure" gliding species (WITHOUT ability of active flight).

Comment: @LadislavNado: Are you sure? **Soaring Birds Are gliding birds.** Moreover, flight pattern of  Archaeopteryx is still under research.

Comment: Thank you @Devashish Das for updating your answer! Opisthocomus hoazin is a great example!!! If you in future find another similar species, please add it. Many thanks again, I will use Opisthocomus hoazin for my popular science lecture where I wil make acknowledges to you ;)

Comment: I think [this](https://prehistoric-fauna.com/image/cache/data/size/Argentavis-738x591.jpg) might be a better approximation of the most current consensus for the comparative size of Argentavis to humans than the one you've used?